# Converting spark data frame to Pandas dataframe showing an error

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

Dears,

I'm fetching data from Hive table to spark data frame and then converting to pandas.

```
sp_df=sqlContext.sql(" \
select * from table1 "\)

sp_df.count()
# 56113241 -- rows

pd_df = sp_df.toPandas()
```

showing an error after taking very long time the below error .:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 5 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down

could you please help me how can we resolve such error. 56million records are unable to convert to pandas.

Comment: Have you try with less data? Try with 5 records, add your data in your post and copy all your result and that you want.

Comment: As @B.Hel suggested try with a little amount of data. Error maybe because you are running out of memory

Comment: with less amount of data like 1000 or 2000 records it's working fine.   this is the configuration i'm using in jupyter notebook:conf = {'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled':'true','spark.executor.instances' : 5, 'spark.executor.memory' : '8g', 'spark.executor.cores':'5','spark.driver.maxResultSize':'8g'}